# bootstrap date picker returns NaN undefined NaN on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using a bootstrap datepicker to input dates in a input/text element.  It works fine if I click an actual date in the graphic calendar, but if I click in a whitespace area on the graphic, it returns a value of 'NaN Undefined NaN' in the input box.

```
<Input type='text' id='startDatePicker' class='watchlistDateInput' name='startDatePicker' placeholder='<%= data.SearchStart %'>
```

Here's the JavaScript setup for the datepicker:

```
// build start datepicker ui
var startPicker = $('#startDatePicker').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'img/calendar-blu.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showOtherMonths: false,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
});
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem, or similar questions, dealing with the calendar click, not just typing the date in the input field?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the HTML code of your `input`.

Comment: <Input type='text' id='startDatePicker' class='watchlistDateInput' name='startDatePicker' placeholder='<%= data.SearchStart %>

Comment: It is being fed data by a underscore template for the <%=data.SearchStart%>

Comment: Kicking it back to front